# New Room Owners for TNB - Nominations Phase

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

**Nomination phase is over. You can vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22045/68942) until UTC midnight on Tuesday, April 20th**

By [community consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20884/68942), we will be having more room owners for [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). We will be selecting new room owners via the following process:

- For one week (lasting until UTC midnight on Tuesday, April 13th), nominations will be accepted as answers on this meta post. Votes here don't matter. You may nominate yourself, and if you are nominated by someone else, please indicate whether or not you accept the nomination as a comment under the nomination or via some reasonable method.
- After the nominations period, an election will be held lasting one week. This will be on a separate meta post.
- Once the election ends, the four nominees with the highest scores will be reviewed by the current moderators for approval and instatement as new room owners.

In each nomination, please include:

- The user being nominated
- Common active times in chat
- A short blurb about why this user would be a good room owner

Votes here won't matter, but feel free to do it anyway :P

Comment: If you would like a bit of a style guide for nominations, the nominations for the [last time we did this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11320/68942) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 18):

## (Self-)Nomination for caird coinheringaahing

- [My chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/274572)
- I'm active pretty much all days, between 10:00 UTC and 3:00 UTC

**Why me?**

I'm extremely active in chat (my [activity lines up with TNB's room activity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57555768#57555768) almost perfectly, and, as [pointed out by Adám](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21986/66833), I am one of 2 nominees who is ["frequently in the room"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?id=240&tab=general&users=frequent)). I post around 100 messages a day, and average around 700 a week. I also have a solid amount of knowledge into the mechanics of being a room owner (I'm an RO in more than 20 rooms), and so are more than familiar with the tools.

Additionally, I'm often the "buzzkill" user whenever fun but noisy conversations happen and I regularly direct users to the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) when they start messing around with chat features in TNB. That doesn't mean I hate fun, but it does mean that I know when an off-topic or noisy conversation needs to stop.

I also [started the discussion into needing more room owners](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20881/66833), [pushed the mods (repeatedly) to hold this election](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=57415499#57415499), and I created [OldSandboxPosts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21931/introducing-oldsandboxposts), a bot which looks to be a very helpful chat resource.

Overall, I believe that I'm level-headed and experienced with chat moderation, and that I have a good judge of the line between a "fun conversation" and "useless noise".

**Why not me?**

I would say that I can be more immature than I'd like in a room owner. I can't speak to how others see me, but that's definitely something I personally am wary of.

As I said, I'm also often the "buzzkill" user, and can be pretty strongly against conversations that others may find fun. This is often subjective, and I find myself typically leaning towards the stricter side more often, which can annoy people who want to have fun in The Nineteenth Byte.

I'm also active around the same time as a lot of users, so my "moderation coverage" doesn't extend particularly far past most others'

Comment: Why does this have your old username in the title? Muscle memory? Pavlovian conditioning?

Comment: @pxeger What old username? :D

Answer (score 14):

## Self nomination for Bubbler

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/337270/bubbler)
- Online mostly on weekdays (Mon-Fri) from 23:00 UTC (previous day) to 9:00 UTC

  - My timezone is UTC+9.

### Reasons for

- I'm active during the hours when most other users are not.
- I'm not *that* active on chat, but I like to read the chat going on (and occasionally participate), and the TNB tab is always open on my PC.
- I tend to actively participate in meta discussions.
- I won't change my username and avatar in the near future.
- I have over **50k** rep across the network :)

### Reasons against

- I'm rarely active (even online) on weekends.
- It is my first time being an RO, except for a few small rooms I made for LotM. It might take some time to get used to the tools (mainly the moderation stuff).
- Similarly to caird, I may occasionally get too strict with certain kinds of conversation, though these days I tend to let things flow most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

## (self-)Nomination for Lyxal

- [Chat Profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515/lyxal)
- Online mostly everyday from 10pm UTC to 12pm UTC (next day)

During my time on Code Golf, I've been a room owner of 26 (albeit inactive) chatrooms, so I've had experience with the tools available. I've also seen every bit of activity over the last 1 and a half years (at the time of writing, my consecutive day streak was 599 days), so I believe I have a good feel of what the community believes is on/off topic.

### Reasons against

- In the past when I didn't know any better, I have been known to be a little spammy/off-topic/non-serious in chat - mostly when the atmosphere of the room permitted it. However, I do know how to be serious/on-topic when the conversation requires such an attitude.
- I'm asleep when most of the active conversations happen (1pm UTC to 9pm UTC), so if anything happens then, I won't be able to do anything.

### Reasons for

- The hours I'm awake coincide with the sleeping hours of some of the more active users (e.g. caird, redwolf, user/Original Original Original VI). Consequently, I'm able to moderate the periods when other users are physically unable to do so - I've noticed that there's a 1-3 hour gap (7am UTC - 10am UTC) when there is a potential for spam to go unfiltered.
- I ain't changing my username/pfp anytime soon
- I won't kill conversations purely because they are off-topic - so long as anyone log-reading the room's transcripts to catch-up on messages won't feel like they are wasting their time, the conversation is fine.

Answer (score 8):

## (Self-)Nomination for Redwolf Programs

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/347075/redwolf-programs)
- Online Monday to Friday from 13:00 to 4:00 (UTC, with some variation)

### Reasons against:

- I seem to be awake at around the same time as existing users

### Reasons for:

- I have experience moderating (and developing!) chat rooms (outside SE)
- I'm quite active on chat and main

Answer (score 8):

## Self-nomination for Adám

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/130368/adam)
- Active in chat 05:00–02:00 UTC

### Reasons for

- As of writing, caird coinheringaahing and I are the only eligible ["frequently in room" users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?id=240&tab=general&users=frequent).
- I have [plenty of rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m?tab=topactivity) to handle flags.
- I have written [over 100 posts on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m?tab=topactivity) throughout the last 5½ years.
- I have written [over 19000 messages in TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?id=240&tab=general&users=frequent#user-130368) throughout the last 4½ years.
- I have 4 years experience as room owner of [another room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard/) that has at times rivalled TNB's activity.
- I have never changed my avatar (as far as I remember), nor do I plan to do that.
- I have only changed my username (other than styling) when [I changed my name in real life](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46212513#46212513).
- I have a reputation to uphold, because my profile is actually [real-life me](https://www.dyalog.com/meet-team-dyalog.htm#Adam).

### Reasons against

- [I am mainly here for work](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11755/43319), so I could be seen as biased.
- In a recent incident, [some people think I handled myself badly as room owner](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/commentary/orchard.html).
- I'm never here on Saturdays, and occasionally I am absent for up to 3 days straight.

Answer (score 6):

## (Self-)Nomination for user

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/468262)
- Only pretty much the entire week from approximately 2 pm UTC to 1 am UTC (not sure about this, though, timezones are confusing)

### Reasons for

- I'm pretty active in TNB, even more than on the main site.
- I'm active on weekdays, although perhaps less so than on weekends.
- I have >10k rep network-wide, meaning I can handle flags raised in the room.
- I'm active when TNB is the most active and action by a room owner will most likely be needed.
- <s>I have a cool and original username, although I'm going to change it back to "user" soon (and I'll be sticking with that).</s> I'm user again, and will likely keep the username and avatar as long as I'm on SE.

### Reasons against

- I can be immature, although that will change if I become a room owner (even if I don't, probably).
- I haven't been a user on CGCC as long as others, such as caird coinheringaahing/ChartZ Belatedly or Lyxal.
- I don't have 10k rep on CGCC, so I can't see deleted posts, etc.
- There's probably more reasons, but I can't think of any right now. That's probably a reason against, though.

Answer (score 1):

## (Self-Nomination) for Wasif

- [Chat Profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/448660)
- Online everyday in week around at varying times (Mostly around UTC 2:00 to 4:30 PM and 7:00 to 12:00 AM and 10:00 to 12:00 AM) (UTC time can be incorrect here is the GMT 6 time I'm mostly active: 1:00-3:30, 5:00-6:30, 9:30-11:30)

## Reasons for

- I am quite active in chat, and could be freely contacted
- Have >20k network reputation, so I'll be able to handle flags and other stuff
- I'm active when TNB is the most active and action by a room owner will most likely be needed.
- I'll never change my username (But avatars can be changed frequently)

## Reasons against

- I don't have 10k on CGCC main, so some problems can occur
- I can be slightly immature, but I am learning more and more
- (Can't think of more reasons please ping me if you find more flaws :P)

Answer (score 0):

## (Self-)Nomination for Wezl

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/456827/wezl)
- Online Monday-Saturday at varying times (around 12:00 to 01:00 UTC?)

### Raisins against:

- I'm active in chat, *even more than on main*.
- My sleep schedule is not crazy

### Raisins for:

- I'm first :P
- I'm *active* in chat, even more than on main.

Comment: One potential con for you is that you have <10k total network rep, meaning that you are unable to handle any flags raised in the room

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Agreed. I'd suggest Wezl focus on participating in asking/answering more in order to gain more experience. Also, helping with the moderation queue when able.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ..ok