# Vote for your new TNB Room Owners!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) is getting four new room owners. You've had a week for [nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21972/new-room-owners-for-tnb-nominations-phase), and now it's time to vote. In alphabetical order, here are the nominees:

- **Adám**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/130368) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21986) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22046)
- **Bubbler**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/337270) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21978) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22047)
- **caird coinheringaahing**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/274572) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/66833) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21976) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22048)
- **Lyxal**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78850) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21974) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22049)
- **Redwolf Programs**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/347075) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/79857) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21975) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22050)
- **user**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/468262) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95792) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21977) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22051)
- **Wasif**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/448660) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92116) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21982) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22052)
- **Wezl**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/456827) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90614) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/90614) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21973) | [vote here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22053)

Each candidate has an answer below. You may vote on as many as you want, and the candidates are welcome to vote as well, including for (or against) themselves.

Voting will close in a week (UTC midnight on Tuesday, April 20th). At the end of the election, we (the moderators) will review the four candidates with the most votes for approval and instatement as new room owners.

Best of luck to all candidates!

**Important note**: serial voting detection applies to meta as well. If you vote for several candidates within a short span of time, your votes may be automatically cancelled. Make sure you check back before the voting period closes to make sure your votes went through.

Answer (score 26):

### [Bubbler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/337270)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/337270) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21978)

Chat user since 2018-02-26.

53 messages this week. 45 messages last week. 75 messages per week.

Answer (score 25):

### [caird coinheringaahing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/274572)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/274572) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/66833) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21976)

Chat user since 2017-04-01.

1k messages this week. 860 messages last week. 809 messages per week.

Answer (score 22):

### [Adám](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/130368)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/130368) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21986)

Chat user since 2014-10-23.

429 messages this week. 285 messages last week. 303 messages per week.

Answer (score 19):

### [Redwolf Programs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/347075)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/347075) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/79857) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21975)

Chat user since 2018-04-17.

1.1k messages this week. 743 messages last week. 672 messages per week.

Answer (score 12):

### [Lyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78850) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21974)

Chat user since 2018-05-31.

876 messages this week. 639 messages last week. 489 messages per week.

Answer (score 8):

### [user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/468262)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/468262) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95792) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21977)

Chat user since 2020-06-29.

941 messages this week. 516 messages last week. 684 messages per week.

Answer (score 3):

### [Wezl](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/456827)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/456827) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90614) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/90614) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21973)

Chat user since 2020-04-20.

303 messages this week. 86 messages last week. 211 messages per week.

Answer (score 2):

### [Wasif](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/448660)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/448660) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92116) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/92116) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21982)

Chat user since 2020-02-22.

318 messages this week. 184 messages last week. 169 messages per week.