# Welcome The Nineteenth Byte's newest room owners!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[The votes are in](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22045/vote-for-your-new-tnb-room-owners?cb=1), and the following four members of our community have been elected as room owners of CGCC's main chat room, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

[image] [image] [image] [image]

They have been instated effective immediately. Please welcome them as our new room owners and join us in thanking them for volunteering.

In the words, of Dennis, may the odds be ever in their favor.